# Bind Expanded & Collapsed event of TreeViewItem to viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Some time ago i asked here how to bind the expanded event to the viewmodel and came to a solution using AttachedCommandBehavior:

```
<TreeView Name="tv" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewElements}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children, Mode=OneTime}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="{Binding Title, Mode=OneTime}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.Event" Value="Expanded"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.ExpandCommand, ElementName=tv}"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

Now it is necessary to bind the collapsed event, too. 
Adding this to the style section like this does not work, only the collapsed event is binded:

```
<Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.Event" Value="Expanded"></Setter>
<Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.ExpandCommand, ElementName=tv}"></Setter>
<Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"></Setter>
<Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.Event" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
<Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.CollapseCommand, ElementName=tv}"></Setter>
<Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"></Setter>
```

Then i found an example on the AttachedCommandBehavior homepage to use a collection of behaviors:

```
<local:CommandBehaviorCollection.Behaviors>
    <local:BehaviorBinding Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Action="{Binding DoSomething}" CommandParameter="An Action on MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
    <local:BehaviorBinding Event="MouseRightButtonDown" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" CommandParameter="A Command on MouseRightButtonDown"/>
</local:CommandBehaviorCollection.Behaviors>
```

The problem is that adding such a collection in the style section does not work, visual studio gives the error that the behavior property can not be attached to style.

Has anybody an idea how i can bind both events to the viewmodel?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
 <Setter Property="local:CommandBehaviorCollection.Behaviors">
  <Setter.Value>
   <local:BehaviorBinding Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Action="{Binding DoSomething}" CommandParameter="An Action on MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
   <local:BehaviorBinding Event="MouseRightButtonDown" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" CommandParameter="A Command on MouseRightButtonDown"/>
  </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately the xaml code doesn't work. I get the error that the behaviors property is no dependency property. Furthermore the beavior property has no setter. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: bummer, have a look at Interaction.Triggers instead, there you can have multiple events.